# Add a key that contains a list in json

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to add a key to a json. I have the following json on a variable:

```
[{"id":00000,"alert":"testing"}]
```

But I need the json object look like this:

```
{'keyA':[{"id":00000,"alert":"testing"}]}
```

How can I concatenate this key to the list?

Thx!

Comment: You don't, just create a new one. `new_obj = {'keyA': old_obj}`

Comment: JSON is a serialized string. Is that thing you show a string or is it a python `list` holding a `dict`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the first object to a new dictionary like this:

```
jsonobj = [{"id":00000,"alert":"testing"}]
result = {'keyA':jsonobj}
```

and then you can either work with this `dictionary` or get the `json` value of it like:

```
import json
json.dumps(result)
```

And if you get only the `json` version of the input you have to use something like:

```
jsonobj = json.loads('[{"alert": "testing", "id": 0}]')
result = {'keyA':jsonobj}
json.dumps(result)
```

Comment: Hi @FlashTek, Im trying this solution, but I'm getting an object like this:
{"keyA": '[{"id":00000,"alert":"testing"}]'}, but I don't want this single quote after KeyA. Is that possible?

Comment: When I execute the first part of my answer I get this result `'{"keyA": [{"alert": "testing", "id": 0}]}'`.

Comment: I got the single quote when I execute the json.dumps(result).